# Devise Unauthorized 401 After Sign In

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using rails 4.1.2 and devise 3.2.4

I've seen this question asked before, and scoured the internet for a solution, but all the recommendations are not working. After a successful sign in ( sign_in_count incremented for member, current_member method returns the correct member ), devise routes back to the original page the member was trying to view, but

```
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 2ms
```

is always the result, and the member is redirected back to the sign in page (sessions#new)

I have the CSRF meta tags in my layout.

I have tried scoping the routes I want to be authenticatable:

```
devise_for :members, :path => '/' # i want sign in path to be /sign_in

devise_scope: :members do
  root 'application#index'
  get 'car_wash/:dealer_id', to: 'car_wash#show'
  post 'car_wash/:id/update', to: 'car_wash#update'
end
```

In controllers I want to be authenticated:

```
before_filter :authenticate_member!
```

In the Members model

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :authenticatable, :rememberable, :trackable, :authentication_keys => [ :username ]
```

The log looks like this:

```
12:26:34 web.1         | Started POST "/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-02 12:26:34 -0500
12:26:34 web.1         | Processing by Members::SessionsController#create as HTML
12:26:34 web.1         |   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓","authenticity_token"=>"4tQIel82ktomEwfsvkgXzB7XfXJlmJxmlea9BnjaIYk=", "member"=>{"username"=>"John", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
12:26:34 web.1         |   Member Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "members".* FROM "members"  WHERE "members"."username" = 'John' LIMIT 1
12:26:35 web.1         |    (0.3ms)  BEGIN
12:26:35 web.1         |    (0.3ms)  COMMIT
12:26:35 web.1         |    (0.2ms)  BEGIN
12:26:35 web.1         |   SQL (0.5ms)  UPDATE "members" SET "current_sign_in_at" = $1, "last_sign_in_at" = $2, "sign_in_count" = $3, "updated_at" = $4 WHERE "members"."id" = 1  [["current_sign_in_at", "2014-07-02 17:26:35.878880"], ["last_sign_in_at", "2014-07-02 17:23:42.608524"], ["sign_in_count", 23], ["updated_at", "2014-07-02 17:26:35.879614"]]
12:26:35 web.1         |    (6.3ms)  COMMIT
12:26:35 web.1         | Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
12:26:35 web.1         | Completed 302 Found in 1408ms (ActiveRecord: 8.6ms)
12:26:35 web.1         |
12:26:35 web.1         |
12:26:35 web.1         | Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-02 12:26:35 -0500
12:26:35 web.1         | Processing by ApplicationController#index as HTML
12:26:35 web.1         | Completed 401 Unauthorized in 2ms
12:26:35 web.1         |
12:26:35 web.1         |
12:26:35 web.1         | Started GET "/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-02 12:26:35 -0500
12:26:35 web.1         | Processing by Members::SessionsController#new as HTML
12:26:35 web.1         |   Rendered devise/shared/_links.erb (0.1ms)
12:26:35 web.1         |   Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (4.2ms)
12:26:35 web.1         |   Rendered shared/_header.html.haml (1.5ms)
12:26:35 web.1         | Completed 200 OK in 24ms (Views: 21.2ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

I am using a custom warden strategy to determine success or fail of the authentication based on a call to an external api. I've stepped through every part of that logic and it is working great!

```
# config/initializers/devise.rb
config.warden do |manager|
  manager.intercept_401 = false
  manager.default_strategies(:scope => :member).unshift :member_login
end
```

But for whaterver reason, the successful sign in is not sticking.

EDIT: Found the solution. The problem was in my custom Warden auth strategy (big surprise):

```
Warden::Strategies.add(:member_login) do
  def member_params
    ActionController::Parameters.new(@response).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :role, :username, :external_api_user_id)
  end

  def valid?
    params[:member] && ( params[:member][:username] || params[:member][:password] )
  end

  def authenticate!
    member = Member.find_by_username(params[:member][:username])
    if authenticate_with_ppd_api
      if member
        member.update(member_params)
        success!(member)
      else
        member = Member.create(member_params)
        success!(member)
      end
    else
      fail!("Incorrect username or password")
    end
  end

  def authenticate_with_api
    @response = HTTParty.post('https://path.to.server/admin/login', body: { username: params[:member][:username], password: params[:member][:password] } )
    @response = JSON.parse(@response.body).first
    @response["authenticated"]
  end

end
```

I was not permitting 'authenticity_token' for member. After adding that, sign in works:

```
ActionController::Parameters.new(@response).permit(:authenticity_token, :first_name, :last_name, :role, :username, :external_api_user_id)
```

This is still very confusing to me. I was only updating/creating a user for my own purposes and not for anything to do with authentication. I have no idea why updating the authenticity token is not happening automatically. It might help if I knew what the default Warden strategy was doing. Oh, well. At least it's working.

EDIT: Oh dear! Well, sign in works, but sign out does not! This 'fix' does make it possible to sign in but not out. Sending a DELETE request to /sign_out does absolutely nothing. Back to square 1